# Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) brainstorming app

Tags: webapp-rec

Does anyone know of apps to plan for a large OOP project?

Like brainstorming, mindmapping etc., but with OOP focus.

I've seen it once, where you could create classes, map them together, see functions, access etc.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a UML editor. Try these

http://www.gliffy.com/

http://yuml.me/

http://creately.com/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) to include only web applications (those that can be run within the browser) here.

Comment: ah, of course - I didn't grok the aims of the site properly - I shall amend my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I often just use the tools in NetBeans to draw conceptual diagrams whereas later I may or may not create an ERD.  If you want something more formal and constrained than "blob" diagrams then it is entirely your discretion to do a proper diagram.  It will do what you ask for but I haven't tried it out myself.

On the other hand, any word processor can be used to produce a scope and **summary** requirements.  Let us say your project had some reasonable basis for doing it, then you might want to confirm through some online research which is also great.

I mention all of this because I am not sure that you need much in the way of tools before that point.  I've usually done most of my brainstorming prior to creating classes and functions and find adding that much detail totally disrupts the thinking process.

Comment: you've fallen into the same trap I did earlier - the OP is looking for WEB APPLICATIONS that provide the required functionality